# Redirect https and http www to https non www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the following

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

tried using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It doesn't seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It will run for `http://example.com` since there is `OR` clause between 2 conditions.

Comment: Yeah I just spotted that, but it does not work for me for some reason :|

Comment: Ah, I think it's because your `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off` has a capital O? On my server, at least, it works when I make this lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the easiest thing to do is just write two rules:

```
# First make sure HTTPS is being used
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Then make sure www isn't being used
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: it is not working (the https part is working) but the www part does not